# Rails. Catch 22 issue seeding database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, seeding

My rails app has `User` and `InviteCode` models. `InviteCode` `belongs_to` `User`

To create new users a valid `invite_code` is needed.
But to create such a code, a `User` is needed in the first place, because of the belong_to relation.

My question is, how can I seed my database ?

**Edit to add how models look**

```
class InviteCode < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :code, presence: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invite_codes, dependent: :destroy

  attr_accessor :invite_code
  validate :invite_code_valid, :on => :create

  def invite_code_valid
    @invite_code = InviteCode.find_by_code(self.invite_code)
    if @invite_code.nil?
      self.errors.add(:invite_code, "invalid")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the models with validations please.  You say about seeding, but I'm not sure how this would work in any other scenario either.

Comment: Can an user have many invitecode?

Answer (score 1):

Right so a User invites other users with an invite code?  And a user needs an invite code to be allowed to sign up?

Remove the validation from User, and have a form object

```
class SignUpsController
  def new
    @sign_up = SignUp.new
  end

  def create
    @sign_up = SignUp.new(sign_up_params)
    if @sign_up.save
      redirect_to @sign_up.user
    else
      render :new
    end

  end
end
```

Model

```
class SignUp
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :invite_code_code, :name

  validates :invite_code, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true

  def invite_code
    InviteCode.find_by(code: invite_code_code)
  end

  def user
    @user ||= User.new(name: name)
  end

  def save
    return unless valid?
    user.save
  end
end
```

View

```
<%= form_for @sign_up, url: sign_ups_path do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :invite_code_code, "Invite Code" %>
    <%= f.text_field :invite_code_code %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Now because the validation is on the `SignUp` not the User model you can create Users without invite codes.  Which is probably better as you can then delete old invite codes and if the user wants to update their profile they won't have an error of not having an invite code

Another way would simply be to seed without validating anything in your seeds file

```
u = User.new(name: "Joe")
u.save(validate: false)
```

Comment: Yes, form objects is the way to go.

Comment: You are right that the validation shouldn't be on `User`, didn't think through editing users... I should also have mentioned I'm using Devise for authentication, so I'm not sure how I could integrate this into my app. I need to study it for a moment to figure things out

Comment: You can generate the devise views and controllers and amend as necessary

Comment: I simply don't understand how to integrate this with Devise, even if I already have controllers and views generated and customized. This is `RegistrationsController`, the equivalent of `SignUpsController`: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb. How to amend it ? I also understand that class `SignUp` ( `Registration` ) should act as a model for the signup form with its own set of validations, so I copied it under `/models/registration.rb`. Haven't changed the view though. And it returns `undefined method invite_code`. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct, but for others who may stumble in here and wish to seed a database.  The seeds.rb file is in the db folder along with your schema.rb and migrate folder.  It operates just like a ruby program.  Here is a good source to learn more: http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/seed_rb.html